# Javascript calculator-emptying the field before typing input

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to build a calculator using JavaScript

```js
    var btn5 = document.getElementById('btn5');
 var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
 var btn5multiply = document.getElementById('btn5multiply');
 var result = document.getElementById('result');
 var calInput = document.getElementById('calInput');
 var backSpace = document.getElementById('backSpace');
 var C = document.getElementById('C');
 var blank = "Please enter a number";

 btn5.addEventListener('click', runFunction5);
 btn2.addEventListener('click', runFunction2);
 multiply.addEventListener('click', multiplyFunction);
 result.addEventListener('click', resultFunction);
 backSpace.addEventListener('click', backSpaceFunction);
 C.addEventListener('click', clearFunction);

 function runFunction5() {

  if(calInput.value == blank) {
   calInput.value = "";
   calInput.value += btn5.value;
  } else {
   calInput.value += btn5.value;
  }
 }

 function runFunction2() {
  calInput.value += btn2.value;
 }

 function multiplyFunction() {
  calInput.value += multiply.value;
 }

 function resultFunction() {

  if(calInput.value == "") {
   calInput.value = blank;
  } else {
   var storeVal = calInput.value;
   var cal = eval(storeVal);
   calInput.value = cal;
  }
 }

 function backSpaceFunction() {
  var storeVal = calInput.value;
  calInput.value = storeVal.substr(0, storeVal.length - 1);
 }

 function clearFunction() {
  calInput.value = "";
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <input id="calInput" type="text" disabled="true" value=""><br><br>
 <button id="backSpace"><-</button>
 <button id="btn5" value="5">5</button>
 <button id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
 <button id="multiply" value="*">X</button>
 <button id="result">=</button>
 <button id="C">C</button>
</body>
```

. In my code if someone presses the =key, it displays the message that says `Please enter a number`. Now I figured out the way to clear the field first when pressing the number key after pressing =key and appending every key pressed afterwards to the input field but there is too much typing of code as I have to assigned that condition to every numeric key, so is there a better way to achieve that ? Right now I have added that condition to only when 5 is pressed.

Comment: Read a bit about event delegation. You can have one function handle multiple clicks by having the event bubble up to a common parent node.

Comment: And use classes!

Comment: Some advice wrap everything in a `<form>`  and use `type=number` for `<input>`s. Google *HTMLFormControlsCollection* You need to build on a better base of code before you have a hundred functions.

Comment: @zer00ne `form` is only required when submitting data and the `forms` collection will work, but is the way we accessed form elements about 100 years ago.

Comment: Which one is easier: `var btn = document.forms[0].elements` then `btn[1].value` for each button or `var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1').value` for each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is assign a common function to each of the buttons for their `click` event and within that handler, you can determine which button was actually clicked using the `event.target`.

Now, there's no need for an `input` field here at all. You aren't getting any input directly from it, you are actually using it as an output mechanism. Since you want it placed on its own line, a regular `div` is the better UI choice.

Next, instead of getting the `value` of your buttons, just work with the text that is the content of the buttons via the `.textContent` property of the element. This will make the HTML much simpler as well.

Now, you have `eval()` in your code as a way of taking the string you've built up and running it as an expression. `eval()` should be avoided all the time. There is hardly a use-case that requires it. It opens up security and performance problems in an application. This is a topic of some debate, but in my opinion, anyone that advocates for it is under-informed about `eval()` or JavaScript. It will take a little more code, but you can do the math without it.

This example answers your question and demonstrates my suggestions. I've even extended your scenario to include all the basic math operators, but there is still more that would need to be flushed on on this before it was ready for production deployment.

```js
// Get both number buttons in an array:
var btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".number"));

// Get all operator buttons in an array:
var operators = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".operator"));
var operator = null;  // Will store the last operator pressed

var result = document.getElementById('result');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var back = document.getElementById('backspace');
var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
var blank = "Please enter a number";

// Loop over the buttons in the numbers array
btns.forEach(function(btn){
  // Assign an event handler to the button
  btn.addEventListener("click", btnFunction);
});

// Loop over the buttons in the operators array
operators.forEach(function(op){
  // Assign an event handler to the button
  op.addEventListener("click",  function (evt) {
    operator = evt.target.textContent;   // Get the operator and store it
    output.textContent += operator;      // Display the operator in the expression    
  });
});

// Set up event handlers:
result.addEventListener("click", doMath);
clear.addEventListener("click", function() { output.textContent = ""; });
back.addEventListener("click", function(){
  output.textContent = output.textContent.substring(0, output.textContent.length - 1);
});

// All event handling functions are automatically passed
// a reference to the event that triggered the function
function btnFunction(evt) {
  // And that event object exposes the actual DOM object
  // that triggered the event via the target property
  if(output.textContent == blank) {
    output.textContent = evt.target.textContent;
  } else {
      output.textContent += evt.target.textContent;
  }
}

function doMath() {
  // Check for no math to do yet
  if(output.textContent === ""){
    output.textContent = blank;
  }

  // Break up the expression into an array with the operands serving to delimit the parts
  var operands = output.textContent.split(/[+-/*]/);

  // Do the math:
  switch (operator){
    case "+" :
      // Operands is an array, so we want to do the math with the two items in the array which
      // we get by passing indexes of 0 and 1 to the array.
      output.textContent += " = " + (parseInt(operands[0], 10) + parseInt(parseInt(operands[1], 10)));
      break;
    case "-" :
      output.textContent += " = " +  (parseInt(operands[0], 10) - parseInt(parseInt(operands[1], 10)));
      break;
    case "*" :
      output.textContent += " = " +  parseInt(operands[0], 10) * parseInt(parseInt(operands[1], 10));
      break;
    case "/" :
      output.textContent += " = " +  parseInt(operands[0], 10) / parseInt(parseInt(operands[1], 10));
      break;        
  }
}
```

```css
#output { height:1em; padding:3px; }
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- No need for an input element here. -->
 <div id="output"></div>
  
 <button id="backspace">&larr;</button>
 <button class="number">5</button>
 <button class="number">2</button>
 <button class="operator">+</button>
 <button class="operator">-</button>
 <button class="operator">*</button>
  <button class="operator">/</button>
 <button id="result">=</button>
 <button id="clear">C</button>
</body>
```

Comment: That was one hell of a explanation

Comment: @AseemSharma If you like it, please up vote the answer. If it solves your problem, please mark it as "the" answer.

Comment: Can you please explain this `function btnFunction(evt)`. I think it is also not working because when I click on =button it shows NaN instead of "Please enter a number"

Comment: `btnFunction(evt)` is the single function that will be called when any of the "number" buttons are pressed. It accesses the correct number by using the reference to the event (`evt`) that is automatically passed to it with `evt.target`.  I removed the "Please enter a number part", but I will put it back.

Comment: I found out one limitation for this code. Because you are splitting up in array, you can only perform math on just two number. If there are more than two numbers involved, it will only give you the output of just first two numbers, eg - 5+2+5 will give you the result of 7 and not 12.

Comment: As I said at the end of my answer, this is code that demonstrates the answer to your question, but needs more work before it’s ready for production. Given that you have to hit an operator button between each operand, storing the previous part of the expression is trivial.

Comment: Can you please explain a littile about this `var operands = output.textContent.split(/[+-/*]/);
` and this `(parseInt(operands[0], 10) + parseInt(parseInt(operands[1], 10)))` so that I can research about it on internet

Comment: The `var operands` part does what it says in the comment above it. it takes an expression like this, for example: `5+2` and splits it into an array of `["5","2"]` and then the `parseInt` line takes the first and second elements in the array and converts them to numbers and does the math.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the value of the *currently clicked* button, like this:

```
function numberClickHandler() {
    calInput.value += this.value;
}
```

Now we only need to assign this to all buttons, e.g.:

```
["btn2", "btn3"].forEach(id =>
  document
    .getElementById(id)
    .onclick = numberClickHandler
);
```

Comment: I did not get this

Answer (score 0):

A little modification in the HTML will solve your issue. I suggest you add a `placeholder` attribute in the input. Placeholder will disappear once there is a value in input and will reappear when there is none.

More about placeholder: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2194/

**HTML**:

```
<input id="calInput" type="text" disabled="true" value="" placeholder="Please enter a number">
<br>
<br>
<button id="backSpace">>
</button>
<button id="btn5" value="5">5</button>
<button id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
<button id="multiply" value="*">X</button>
<button id="result">=</button>
<button id="C">C</button>
```

**JS**:

```
var btn5 = document.getElementById('btn5');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var btn5multiply = document.getElementById('btn5multiply');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var calInput = document.getElementById('calInput');
var backSpace = document.getElementById('backSpace');
var C = document.getElementById('C');
var blank = "Please enter a number";

btn5.addEventListener('click', runFunction5);
btn2.addEventListener('click', runFunction2);
multiply.addEventListener('click', multiplyFunction);
result.addEventListener('click', resultFunction);
backSpace.addEventListener('click', backSpaceFunction);
C.addEventListener('click', clearFunction);

function runFunction5() {
  calInput.value += btn5.value;
}

function runFunction2() {
  calInput.value += btn2.value;
}

function multiplyFunction() {
  calInput.value += multiply.value;
}

function resultFunction() {
  var storeVal = calInput.value;
  var cal = eval(storeVal);
  calInput.value = cal;
}

function backSpaceFunction() {
  var storeVal = calInput.value;
  calInput.value = storeVal.substr(0, storeVal.length - 1);
}

function clearFunction() {
  calInput.value = "";
}
```

Once, you do that you will not have to add that condition in each case.

Comment: I already knew about the placeholders. Trying it differently for learning purposes

Comment: An `input` is the wrong element to use in the first place in this scenario since it's actually being used for output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var numericValues = document.getElementById('numericValue');
 var result = document.getElementById('result');
 var calInput = document.getElementById('calInput');
 var backSpace = document.getElementById('backSpace');
 var C = document.getElementById('C');
 var blank = "Please enter a number";

 numericValues.addEventListener('click', pushNumericValue);
 multiply.addEventListener('click', multiplyFunction);
 result.addEventListener('click', resultFunction);
 backSpace.addEventListener('click', backSpaceFunction);
 C.addEventListener('click', clearFunction);

 function pushNumericValue(event) {
        var btnTarget = event.target
  if(calInput.value == blank) {
   calInput.value = "";
   calInput.value += btnTarget.value;
  } else {
   calInput.value += btnTarget.value;
  }
 }

 function multiplyFunction() {
  calInput.value += multiply.value;
 }

 function resultFunction() {

  if(calInput.value == "") {
   calInput.value = blank;
  } else {
   var storeVal = calInput.value;
   var cal = eval(storeVal);
   calInput.value = cal;
  }
 }

 function backSpaceFunction() {
  var storeVal = calInput.value;
  calInput.value = storeVal.substr(0, storeVal.length - 1);
 }

 function clearFunction() {
  calInput.value = "";
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <input id="calInput" type="text" disabled="true" value=""><br><br>
 <button id="backSpace"><-</button>
    <div id="numericValue">
   <button id="btn5" value="1">1</button>
   <button id="btn5" value="2">2</button>
   <button id="btn5" value="3">3</button>
   <button id="btn2" value="4">4</button>
    </div>
 <button id="multiply" value="*">X</button>
 <button id="result">=</button>
 <button id="C">C</button>
</body>
```

**One way to do it**
Is using event delegation instead of listening all numeric values and doing an specific action. Define a parent **div** that have as children all numeric values and listen to it thanks to the event.target attribute you can get its value of the clicked button